# get possible values from validation list in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I need to get all the values of a dropdown list of a cell in an excel macro.

I create the dropdown list in this way:

```
    Sub DropDOwn()
'
' DropDOwn Macro
'

'
    Range("F1").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="si;no;a veces"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With



End Sub
```

But I don´t know the way to get using a macro all the possible values of a dropdown list

Comment: You can get it, the same way you set it: `Range("F1").Validation.Formula1`. What is the exact problem?

Comment: My problem is that I don´t know how to get that values from Formula1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on any cell and run:

```
Sub IsIt()
    On Error GoTo trap
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
trap:
    MsgBox "no data validation"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

to get the string of items applied with *Formula1* or an error message.